# svelte app serving from a subfolder without sapper

Tags: svelte

How can I host an exported Svelte project in a subdirectory on my domain?

I have a domain with /name-of-page and I want to be /subdir/name-of-page on the live

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Are you starting from scratch? If so, what kind of hosting are you considering? Serverless, PaaS, IaaS? If you have an existing site: how is it hosted?

Comment: No, I’m not starting from scratch, it’s an already existent project and I just want to build for production. For example in the vuejs project this is simple by adding in the vuejs.config.js the below code and all the site will be build with the paths with /my-subdir/ at the begining.
module.exports = {
  publicPath: “/my-subdir/”
};

Answer (score 0):

I think a you should compile your app ass `webcomponent/custom-Element` when you like to use it as a component (a complete app inside another project can be identified as component?!)

Svelte can compile to custom element out of the box. See:

- https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/797

Here is an example how i solved this for a component working as svelte component and as custom element:
https://github.com/ivosdc/svelte-generic-crud-table

(have a look at the shadow-dom handling).

- A good introduction into webcomponents for svelte is:
  https://dev.to/silvio/how-to-create-a-web-components-in-svelte-2g4j